# How can I set panel to bottom, after installing MATE 1.4?

Tags: mate

How can I move the Ubuntu 12.10 top panel to bottom, after installing MATE 1.4? How can I do that after removing it from top ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AskUbuntu.  We like discrete questions that can be answerable.  So feel free to ask your Mate Menu question separately if it has not already been raised.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting the panel as in the other answer, right click on panel then click properties and change the Orientation on the General tab.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just right click on panel,create another panel & delete  the top one. Then  configure all indicators on bottom panel in settings -right click
[image]